# LSTM autoencoder on sequences - what loss function?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to construct an LSTM autoencoder on sequences of text (titles of web articles) mostly by reproducing the mentioned basic example in https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html. The input are 80 (maximum title length) one-hot vectors of length 40 (number of ascii characters in dataset). The output, against which the predictions are checked, is the same as input, because it is an autoencoder. I have about 60k sequences for testing the model, but ultimately, I would like to run it on the whole set of 320k.

### Problem

But the problem is, that the LSTM network isn't learning properly at all. For instance, the Czech sentence 'Real vyhrál slavné derby s Barcelonou' gets reproduced as '###uuu...uuu' (dots mean, that the u's continue till the end).

In the tutorial above, it doesn't mention what loss function, activation function or optimizer to use, so I searched and found, that with LSTMs *RMSProp* optimizer works the best. I tried RELU, Tanh, Softmax etc. as activation functions, though none of them did any better. What I am hesitating most about is the loss function. I thought that binary or categorical cross-entropy would work nicely, but this just might be where I am mistaken. Mean squared error didn't yield any good results either.

## My model thus far

```
input_sentence = Input(shape=(max_title_length, number_of_chars), dtype='int32')
tofloat = Lambda(function=lambda x: tf.to_float(x))(input_sentence)
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, activation='tanh')(tofloat)

decoder = RepeatVector(max_title_len)(encoder)
decoder = LSTM(number_of_chars, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(decoder)
autoencoder = Model(input=input_sentence, output=decoder)

autoencoder.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## So the questions

1. What loss function would you use?
2. Does the binary/categorical cross-entropy calculate loss for the entire output matrix or for individual timesteps (rows in the output matrix)? I would like to achieve the latter.
3. If you think this approach isn't going to work, would you suggest a different one?

Comment: This question might be better answered at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better loss function for your case is "Hamming loss" that computes the average Hamming loss or Hamming distance between two sets of samples.
Thus you can compute distances between all rows from a matrix.

Example with `sckit-learn` and `numpy`:

```
>>> hamming_loss(np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1]]), np.zeros((2, 2)))
0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think your model has many more issues and not just a matter of what functions to use. The model itself needs to be fixed first before any experimentation with the loss and optimization functions.
2. When you use a stacked version of LSTM like an autoencoder, you need to pass around the hidden and cell states from the encoder to the decoder for the decoder to have more context.
3. Also if you are working with a language model, it would be much better to use a word model rather than a letter's model. Try to preprocess your data to create a bag of words and then one hot encode them like you did with the letters.
4. After that I would suggest you adding more encoders and decoders to the network like so:

   ```py
   import tensorflow as tf

   n_input_words = 100
   n_features = 10000
   latent_dim = 100
   n_future = 10

   encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_input_words, n_features))
   encoder_l1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences = True, return_state=True)(encoder_inputs)
   encoder_states1 = encoder_l1[1:]
   encoder_l2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)(encoder_l1[0])
   encoder_states2 = encoder_l2[1:]

   decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(n_future)(encoder_l2[0])
   decoder_l1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)(decoder_inputs,initial_state = encoder_states1)
   decoder_l2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)(decoder_l1,initial_state = encoder_states2)
   decoder_outputs2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_features, input_shape = decoder_l2.shape)(decoder_l2)
   model_e2d2 = tf.keras.models.Model(encoder_inputs,decoder_outputs2)
   model_e2d2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

   model_e2d2.summary()
   ```

As for your loss function, I think KL Divergence or Huber would perform well.